# can hbbtv app get access to EIT inside of a host?

Tags: html, dvb, epg

Does anybody know if hbbtv application being running in hbbtv enabled host (like iDTV or STB) can get access to EITs that come with a DVB stream, not through internet?

regards
alex

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can: you will need to use the "MetadataSearch" object. This is documented in section 7.12 of vol. 5 ("DAE") of the OIPF Specification v1.2. You can download that document from: http://www.oipf.tv/specifications/login/com-sef-users-download?gid=83

Using the APIs is a little bit involved; you need to create a query object, set the query, execute it, wait for the message saying the search completed (or failed - in which case you need to handle the error) and then you can retrieve the results. For example;

```
var search_manager = window.oipfObjectFactory.createSearchManagerObject();
var search = search_manager.createSearch(1);
var results = null;
/* eg; restrict results to a single channel
 * (You'll need to get a channel object from one of the many APIs that do that)
 */
search.addChannelConstraint(channel);
// Get a programme starting at or after 1:01 on 1/1/2000:
var query = search.createQuery("Programme.startTime", 3, '949366860');
search.setQuery(query);
search_manager.addEventListener("MetadataSearch", function() {
    results = search.result;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        // do something
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: You can also use the .programmes property of the video/broadcast object. See http://itv.mit-xperts.com/hbbtvtest/eitevent/